# How to do a matrix multiplication using <threads> and a 1-D array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, matrix, c++14

I am trying to do a matrix multiplication using threads. But I do not get correct values. Since the matrix can be very large I use the heap memory. The matrix is thus stored in a 1-D array.

The matrix is always a square matrix thus the number of rows and the number of columns is equal to the square root of the array length. If the array length is 16 then the numbers of rows is 4 and the number of columns is also 4.

I can not use an `std::vector` so that's why the use of `std::unique_ptr`.

There are 4 threads and each of them receives 1/4 of the original array to work with. This doesn't work due to the nature of matrix multiplication and I can't seem to find the right solution. **How can I split the task for 4 threads**?

```
auto matrixmultiplication(float* &array1, float* &array2, int arrayLength) {
    unique_ptr<float[]> arrayOut(new float[arrayLength]);
    auto numberOfThreads = 4;
    auto widthMatrix = (int)sqrt(arrayLength);
    auto elementsPerThread = (int)sqrt(arrayLength / numberOfThreads);

    auto mul = [](auto* array1, auto* array2, auto* array3, auto dimension) {
        for (auto x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
            for (auto y = 0; y < dimension; y++) {
                array3[dimension * x + y] = 0;
                for (auto z = 0; z < dimension; z++) {
                    array3[dimension * x + y] += array1[dimension * x + z] * array2[dimension * z + y];
                }
            }
        }
    };

    vector<thread> threads;
    for (auto i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        threads.push_back(
            thread(
                mul,
                array1 + i * elementsPerThread,
                array2,
                arrayOut.get() + i * elementsPerThread,
                elementsPerThread
            )
        );
    }
    for (auto &thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
    return arrayOut;
};
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why are you using a `unique_ptr` for an array instead of e.g. `std::vector`? Same with the `array1` and `array2` arguments, why not `std::vector` or `std::array`? And why are you passing the pointers by reference? And why do you have a vector of pointers to `std::thread` instead of a vector of plain `std::thread` instances? As a general tip, you should avoid pointers as much as possible.

Comment: I use unique_ptr instead of std::vectors or std::array in order to stay consistent with the code base that I received. The code base uses unique_ptr or only standard pointer arrays. For the second one, I thought that passing pointer by reference offers more possibilities such as setting the pointer to zero after deleting it. I removed the pointers of std::thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all threads I would start the processing from consecutive rows of the first matrix , i.e. the 0th thread will process the 0th row, the 1st will process 1st row, and so on to the nth thread.

After a thread processed a row it has to jump to the next row by the number of threads, i.e. if I have 2 threads, after the 0th finished processig the 0th row, it will jump to the 2nd row and process it.

Let's see it in a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

// multiplies the specified row and column from specified matrices
void multiply(const int* m_1, const int* m_2,
        std::size_t size, std::size_t row, std::size_t col, int* m_res) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        m_res[row * size + col] += m_1[row * size + i] * m_2[i * size + col];
}

int main() {
    constexpr int N = 3, THREAD_NUM = 2;

    // matrices to multiply and a matrix for result
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> A(new int[N * N] {
        11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33
    });
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> B(new int[N * N] {
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
    });
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> C(new int[N * N] {});

    // create vector for running threads then assign threads to its elements
    std::vector<std::thread> thread_group(THREAD_NUM);

    for(int thread_i = 0; thread_i < THREAD_NUM; ++thread_i)
        thread_group[thread_i] = std::thread([&, thread_i]() {

            // each thread stars from consecutive rows then steps by 
            // the number of threads
            for(int row = thread_i; row < N; row += THREAD_NUM) {
                for(int col = 0; col < N; ++col)
                    multiply(A.get(), B.get(), N, row, col, C.get());
            }
        });

    for(auto& t : thread_group)
        t.join();

    // show the result
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            std::cout << (j ? "\t" : "") << C[i * N + j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful ! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have two matrices that you want to multiply, let's call them `A` and `B`, you just need to split the matrix `A` row-wise into 4 parts and pass the parts to corresponding threads. When it comes to matrix `B`, you need to pass a reference to the whole matrix to each thread as you need all its elements to calculate each row of `A*B`. This is going to be thread-safe as you are going to only read from the matrix `B` without modyfing it.

Comment: By the time that I could try your idea, @Akira provided a working solution.

Comment: Glad that you have the solution to your problem anyway :) If you are about maximum performance you may want to try also this solution in the future as well as iterating through matrix continously might be faster than jumping between rows as in the other solution, but the difference is probably not going to be spectacular.